# Running Expresso TDD in Node.js on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Environment:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- node.js v0.6.7
- npm 1.1.0-beta-10
- expresso 0.9.2

I've successfully installed via npm from zip download (after modifying package.json to remove node-jscoverage dependence). 'npm ls' lists expresso as installed. After overcoming the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890497/invoke-the-process-addlistener-and-node-tell-me-no-such-module) by commenting out the reference to SIGINT, expresso will execute from cmd window. However, when I actually attempt to run test suites, I get a 'Cannot find module' error when it tries to open the first test suite. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to install the module locally, too.

Comment: I'll give that a try. However, the same install configuration works on Ubuntu, just not on Windows.

Comment: No luck - same error as before, even installed in the project directory. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)? It's supposed to be expresso's successor, written by the same author.

Comment: I've seen mocha before, but the open-source project I'm contributing to is still using expresso.