# Expresso not installing on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, expresso

Having a problem install Expresso on my machine similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781135/running-expresso-tdd-in-node-js-on-windows)

windows 7 x64
node.js version: 0.8.0
npm version: 1.1.32

```
> npm install expresso
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/expresso
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/expresso

> expresso@0.9.2 preinstall C:\node_modules\expresso
> make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage

make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x0x770843f9)
npm ERR! expresso@0.9.2 preinstall: `make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage"` failed with 255
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the expresso@0.9.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the expresso package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls expresso
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\n
\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "expresso"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.32
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message expresso@0.9.2 preinstall: `make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage"` failed with 255
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I too have been trying to install expresso on windows. So far I have not figured out how, but it would appear that the make file is geared specifically toward a Linux/Unix type machine. The reason I say this is that I tried just installing just expresso "make install-expresso" and it died when attempting to change to the \usr\local\bin directory, which I believe is a Linux directory, but I know is not a windows directory. I don't know much about make files, as this is the first time i've ever actually used it, but I've coded msbuild files, so maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: node.jscoverage requires a Unix-like environment to build, that's why installing expresso failed. There is already an opened issue (https://github.com/visionmedia/expresso/issues/159) for this - I wil have a look on it the next weeks.

Answer (score 0):

clone the module using git clone command and use the code locally.